# Is it possible to specify the Update Sequence from which to start a CouchDB replication?

Tags: couchdb, database-replication

I'm using CouchDB in an application that has `Account` objects, `Event` objects and `Ticket` objects (one-to-many-to-many). The basic setup is that each `Account` has its own database, in which all the `Event` and `Ticket` objects are stored, and each `Ticket` object stores a reference to its parent `Event` object. The events and tickets are then consumed by a mobile client application following the `_changes` feed for the database.

I've come to a point where the primary database has become so big that the `_changes` feed being consumed has become unbearably slow. So my plan is to have another database for each `Event` object that only contains tickets for that event, but I still need to keep the primary database for other reasons. So I'm setting up a replication from the primary database to the event database using a filter that only allows tickets for the correct event to pass through.

Because creating an event is a discreet operation, I know that the replication for a new event can start from the *update sequence* for the primary database before the event is created, negating the need for it to run through all the previous documents that are irrelevant. So my question is: when I start a replication can I specify from where it should start? Basically like passing a `?since=XXX` to the `_changes` feed on the mobile client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. Just add the `since_seq` attribute to the [replication document](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/json-structure.html#replication-settings).